# SQL Server docker fails to start on Docker Mac Desktop using compose configuration

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

Use case: 
I want to start SQL Server via docker on my mac for test and dev purposes.
As I do not want to loose my databases switching docker containers I want to use volumes.

Using docker volumes I can do that.

`docker run --name 'mssql' -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=SuperSecret' -p 1433:1433 -v mssqldata:/var/opt/mssql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server`

But on mac the volume data is also stored inside the VM.

So next I tried to setup a docker compose configuration to store files on my favorite place.

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/Users/rausch/Documents/docker-volumes/mssql/data'

services:
  sql1:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: 1sa!1234
      MSSQL_PID: Standard
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/opt/mssql
```

Starting this with

`docker compose -f myconfig.yml up`

The sql server starts and start copy the files to my defined location

[image]

But the docker image exists with error.
Here the output:

```
Creating volume "documents_dbdata" with local driver
Creating documents_sql1_1 ... done
Attaching to documents_sql1_1
sql1_1  | SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
sql1_1  | This container is running as user mssql.
sql1_1  | To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
sql1_1  | 2020-05-30 07:27:18.60 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf'.
2020-05-30 07:27:19.67 Server      Did not find an existing master data file /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf, copying the missing default master and other system database files. If you have moved the database location, but not moved the database files, startup may fail. To repair: shutdown SQL Server, move the master database to configured location, and restart.
2020-05-30 07:27:19.70 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\mastlog.ldf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf'.
2020-05-30 07:27:19.79 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\model.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/model.mdf'.
2020-05-30 07:27:19.98 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\modellog.ldf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/modellog.ldf'.
2020-05-30 07:27:20.17 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\msdbdata.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/msdbdata.mdf'.
2020-05-30 07:27:20.47 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\msdblog.ldf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/msdblog.ldf'.
2020-05-30 07:27:20.55 Server      Setup step is FORCE copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\model_replicatedmaster.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/model_replicatedmaster.mdf'.
2020-05-30 07:27:20.70 Server      Setup step is FORCE copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\model_replicatedmaster.ldf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/model_replicatedmaster.ldf'.
2020-05-30 07:27:20.78 Server      Setup step is FORCE copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\model_msdbdata.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/model_msdbdata.mdf'.
2020-05-30 07:27:21.02 Server      Setup step is FORCE copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\model_msdblog.ldf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/model_msdblog.ldf'.
2020-05-30 07:27:22.99 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU4) (KB4548597) - 15.0.4033.1 (X64) 
sql1_1  Mar 14 2020 16:10:35 
sql1_1  Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
sql1_1  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS) <X64>
2020-05-30 07:27:23.01 Server      UTC adjustment: 0:00
2020-05-30 07:27:23.02 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2020-05-30 07:27:23.03 Server      All rights reserved.
2020-05-30 07:27:23.04 Server      Server process ID is 36.
2020-05-30 07:27:23.05 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog'.
2020-05-30 07:27:23.06 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
sql1_1   -d /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf
sql1_1   -l /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf
sql1_1   -e /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
2020-05-30 07:27:23.10 Server      Error: 17113, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2020-05-30 07:27:23.10 Server      Error 87(The parameter is incorrect.) occurred while opening file '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf' to obtain configuration information at startup. An invalid startup option might have caused the error. Verify your startup options, and correct or remove them if necessary.
documents_sql1_1 exited with code 1
```

**So, anyone can tell me what I do wrong?**

Comment: I don't think it's your problem but `- 1433:1433` should probably be `- "1433:1433"`. I know it's titled "ZFS" but a number of people have reported similar Error 87 logs on Windows and macOS with the following issue: [ZFS Support](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/13#issuecomment-276899855); and the response seems to be along the lines of "use a data volume container instead." Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried that, but there is no difference, same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to start on macOS using a [Docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). Note my compose.yml file requires at least version 3.2 to allow the service's volumes definition to work:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  sql1:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      PATH: "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: 1sa!1234
      MSSQL_PID: Standard
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: mssql
        target: /var/opt/mssql
volumes:
  mssql:
    external:
      name: mssql
```

I then launched the container with:

```sh
$ docker volume create mssql
mssql

$ docker volume inspect mssql
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-05-30T09:36:31Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/mssql/_data",
        "Name": "mssql",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]

$ docker-compose -f compose.yml up
# lots of startup log...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, but if I see this correct you do create a volume inside the docker VM instance, not local in your mac file system.

Comment: Derp, you are completely correct. I forgot that on macOS Docker itself runs in its own Hyperkit VM. You can still use the information at [Use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to backup and restore Docker volumes but if you want to inspect the contents of the volume's folders and files yourself you'll need to use `docker run -it` or `screen`. e.g.: `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty` then `ls -la /var/lib/docker/volumes/mssql/_data` from inside the Docker VM (use ctrl-a k to exit the screen session).

Comment: The strange thing is that it works to create my local volume with local files and as you can see it created mdf and log files, but the sqlserver itself exists with an error. That's why I was wondering. My workaround is to use docker cp to copy the files from and to vm-volume in case of anything, but it would be much more nice and easy if volume works. Works fine for me e.g. with minio/minio or solr docker containers already.

Comment: In the ZFS issue I linked in my comment on your Q was a link to a different 2017 issue, [Mapping volumes should be supported for Docker for Mac](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/12). The interesting thing was a quote from an MS engineer saying, "_SQL Server requires underlying filesystems to support the O_DIRECT file option so that we can use asynchronous I/O. It appears that Docker's OS X volume mapper doesn't support this. We also require O_DIRECT because SQL Server expects unbuffered I/O to the disk._". Doesn't appear to have been fixed/worked around yet.

Comment: Ok I updated post there. so my requirement is not possible atm.